# symfony 5 override a2lix translation-form-bundle template not working

Tags: symfony, templates, overriding

i install the a2lix/translation-form-bundle, and i run

```
php bin/console debug:twig @A2lixTranslationForm/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig
```

i get the

```
@A2lixTranslationForm   vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/src/Resources/views/
```

so, i created

```
templates/bundles/TranslationFormBundle/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig
```

when i clean the cache, the override not working. why and how fix it?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path is

```
templates/bundles/**A2lix**TranslationFormBundle/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig
```